# style facebook likebox scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I have searched almost all the stackoverflow answers to change the css for facebook likebox scrollbar. but no use. I am using the following code

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId='id'";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebookname" data-width="315" data-height="600" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-border-color="#e8e8e8"  data-header="false"></div>
```

I have tried the following links

- [Can you style an iframe scrollbar without access to the iframe's css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813177/can-you-style-an-iframe-scrollbar-without-access-to-the-iframes-css)
- [Facebook Like box with scroll-bar - Can it be styled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119398/facebook-like-box-with-scroll-bar-can-it-be-styled)
- [remove facebook likebox scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644209/remove-facebook-likebox-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wont be getting css files to update because the files at the facebook server side we only embed it in our page. You can only give some styling at the time of creating the like box code at facebook api page. like height width. rest you cant change any styling

Answer (score 0):

I was able to style a iframe , using the same class by adding !important while writing css. 
or changing the css onPageload using javascript.

Comment: we cannot insert styles by using !important, as the css is loading directly from from facebook.com/